# Prove or disprove that every finite $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ is generated by a finite partition of $\Omega$.

Tags: measure-theory, set-partition

> Prove or disprove that every finite $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ is generated by a finite partition of $\Omega$.

I have a feeling this must be true, but I could not do more than the following:

Being $\Sigma$ a finite $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, I defined a set $S$ as the set of intersections of two arbitrary sets in $\Sigma$, but I don't know if there is a partition $P$ which is a subset of $S$ and if there is, if the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $P$ is $\Sigma$. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

And if the fact that every finite $\sigma$-algebra can be generated by a finite partition is false, what conditions do the finite $\sigma$-algebra need to have in order for it to be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersection of just two sets from the sigma algebra won't suffice. Let $\mathcal A =\{A_1,A_2,\cdots,A_n\}$ be a finite sigma algebra. Verify the following facts: sets of the form $B_1\cap B_2\cap\cdots \cap B_n$ where  $B_i$ is either $A_i$ or $A_i^{c}$ for each $i$ are disjoint. Though many of them may be empty, their union is $\Omega$. Also prove that each $A_j$ is a union of those sets of the above form where $B_j=A_j$. Now you can easily verify that the partition we have constructed generates the sigma algebra $\mathcal A$.

Comment: I don't understand the second condition to be verified. What do you mean by saying that each $A_j$ is a union of sets with said form where $B_j=A_j$, Does that mean that each $A_j$ is the union of sets with form $A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n$?

Comment: @G Consider $A_1$. Now look at all sets of the form $A_1\cap B_2\cap B_3\cap \cdots\cap B_n$ where $B_2=A_2$ or $B_2=A_2^{c}$,...,$B_n=A_n$ or$B_n=A_n^{c}$. The union of these sets is $A_1$.

Comment: So what is the partition? Are they $B_1\cap...\cap B_n$?

Comment: Yes, non-empty sets among these intersections form a partition.